# I am unable to hide div tag

Tags: javascript, html

Please have a look at the following code :

```
<div id="flashwelcome" style="display: none">
  <h2 align="center">
    <script language="JavaScript1.2">
        var message = "Welcome to Dynamic Report Generation POC"
        var neonbasecolor = "green"
        var neontextcolor = "blue"
        var neontextcolor2 = "red"
        var flashspeed = 200 // speed of flashing in milliseconds
        var flashingletters = 3 // number of letters flashing in neontextcolor
        var flashingletters2 = 1 // number of letters flashing in neontextcolor2 (0 to disable)
        var flashpause = 0 // the pause between flash-cycles in milliseconds
        /**
         * No need to edit below this line
         */
        var n = 0
        if (document.all || document.getElementById) {
            document.write('<font color="' + neonbasecolor + '">')
            for (m = 0; m < message.length; m++)
            document.write('<span id="neonlight' + m + '">' + message.charAt(m) + '</span>')
            document.write('</font>')
        } else {
            document.write(message)
        }
        
        function crossref(number) {
            var crossobj = document.all ? eval("document.all.neonlight" + number) : document.getElementById("neonlight" + number)
            return crossobj
        }
        
        function neon() {
            /**
             * Change all letters to base color
             */
            if (n == 0) {
                for (m = 0; m < message.length; m++)
                crossref(m).style.color = neonbasecolor
            }
        
            /**
             * cycle through and change individual letters to neon color
             */
            crossref(n).style.color = neontextcolor
        
            if (n > flashingletters - 1) crossref(n - flashingletters).style.color = neontextcolor2
            if (n > (flashingletters + flashingletters2) - 1) crossref(n - flashingletters - flashingletters2).style.color = neonbasecolor
        
        
            if (n < message.length - 1) {
                n++
            } else {
                n = 0
                clearInterval(flashing)
                setTimeout("beginneon()", flashpause)
                return
            }
        }
        
        function beginneon() {
            if (document.all || document.getElementById) flashing = setInterval("neon()", flashspeed)
        }
        beginneon();​
    </script>
  </h2>               
</div>
```

and this is how i hide the above `div tag` but it is not getting hidden,

`document.getElementById("flashwelcome").style.display = 'none';`

I don't think that there is some problem but still the div tag is not hidden.

Please help me to find the problem.

Regards

Comment: it is not giving any error, so that i am unable to find and fix

Comment: Semi-colons are not optional. Don't rely on auto-semi-colon insertion.

Comment: probably an incompatible old browser

Comment: Which webbrowser are you using?

Comment: When do you run this hiding code? On document load or immediately? Maybe DOM node hasn't been initialized yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the code to hide the div within a script tag and said script element is embedded within the document **below** where the div with id=flashwelcome is, this should work fine. If it doesn't, check that JavaScript is enabled within your browser.

Ensure your code looks something like this:

```
<div id="flashwelcome">...</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("flashwelcome").style.display = 'none';
</script>
```

Furthermore, you do realise that you're using inline css to hide the "flashwelcome" div initially?

---

As Musa noted in the comments: that javascript you are using within the h2 tag (?) is very old. As for its functionality: are you sure flashing text like that is what your users really want to see on your website?

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript code is really ugly, as everyone else noted here.

However, as far as I can understand,your first use of document.write is overwriting the whole contents of the DOM (i.e. your whole page's contents). Therefore, as soon as the first document.write sentence is executed, your flashwelcome div disappears.

You can find a slightly modified version of your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/carlesandres/eTY4v/

You will notice I moved your `h2` and `flashwelcome div` to document.write sentences. I also added semicolons and curly braces as recommended by JSLint (usual javascript good practices)

Flashing still doesn't work. You will have to figure why. Good luck!